# Mini Calendar day heading not starting on Sunday as first day of week

Tags: solspace-calendar

Here is the code:

```
<!-- Display week day letter heading ( S M T W T F S ) -->
<tr id="mc_days">
  {display_each_day_of_week}
    <th class="{if day_of_week_is_weekend}weekend{/if} 
      {if day_of_week_is_current}current{/if}">{day_of_week_one}
    </th>
  {/display_each_day_of_week}
</tr>
```

What happens is for example June 1 2014 is on on Sunday but my calendar has it on Saturday.

The header format displays as S S M T W T F. If I click my next button to go to the month of July the header changes to F S S M T W T. If I go to August the header displays as S S S M T W T as you can see Friday turns into an S.

Comment: Can you update your OP with the full Calendar code? Also, please provide the Calendar and EE version numbers that you are using. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following in my Calendar widget:

```
{calendar_heading}
   <td class="calendarDayHeading">{lang:weekday_short}</td>
{/calendar_heading}
```

Within my entire calendar widget...:

```
{exp:channel:calendar switch="calendarToday|calendarCell" channel="events" show_future_entries="yes"}
  <table class="calendarBG events-calendar" border="0" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="1" summary="My Calendar">
      <tr class="calendarHeader">
        <th>
            <div class="calendarMonthLinks">
                <a href="{previous_path='events/index'}">&lt;&lt;</a>
            </div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="5" class="calendarMonthTitle"><a href="/events/{date format="%Y/%m"}">{date format="%F %Y"}</a></th>
        <th>
            <div class="calendarMonthLinks">
                <a class="calendarMonthLinks" href="{next_path='events/index'}">&gt;&gt;</a>
            </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      {calendar_heading}
      <td class="calendarDayHeading">{lang:weekday_short}</td>
      {/calendar_heading}
      </tr>
      {calendar_rows}
          {row_start}<tr>{/row_start}
          {if entries}
              <td class='{switch}' align='center'><a href="{day_path='events/index'}">{day_number}</a>
              </td>
          {/if}
          {if not_entries}
              <td class='{switch}' align='center'>{day_number}</td>
          {/if}
          {if blank}
              <td class='calendarBlank'>{day_number}</td>
          {/if}
          {row_end}</tr>{/row_end}
      {/calendar_rows}
    </table>
{/exp:channel:calendar}
```